# The Child SKSpriteKITnodes in the coordinate system doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, coordinate-systems

The Child SKSpriteKITnodes in the coordinate system doesn't work well I am trying to move the SKSprite nodes from Top To Bottom But they Get stop in the middle ?

```
ColorCoin *coin = [[ColorCoin alloc] initWithImageNamed: coinName] ;

SKAction *move = [SKAction moveToY:0 duration: 10];

CGFloat screenWidth = [self dropNode].size.width;


int x = arc4random() % (int) _dropNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame.size.width;

coin.zPosition =0.0;

coin.position = CGPointMake( x, _dropNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame.size.height-30);
coin.name = coinName;

[coin runAction: move];

[[self dropNode] addChild:coin];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `anchorPoint` of an `SKSpriteNode` is `(0.5, 0.5)` by default. Therefore, when `[self dropNode].position.y == 0` it's correct the the child node will be in the middle of its parent `SKSpriteNode`.

If you want the coin to move to the bottom of `dropNode` you can either set the `anchorPoint` of `dropNode` to `(x, 0)` (where `x` is any value in the range 0-1). Or you can change `move` to:

```
SKAction *move = [SKAction moveToY:-screenWidth / 2 duration: 10];
```

Comment: @Aditya Kasturi, that's okay, glad I could help :) Would you consider marking it as correct if it solved your problem?